# Downloading files through command line in Windows

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, download

I would like to download a pdf file from my personal business SharePoint site using a command line in Windows.

My SharePoint site is of format: https://somename.sharepoint.com

I tried the windows version of curl and wget ([curl_link_here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.50.2), [wget_link_here](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)) which seemed a good choice.

I tried several command line options, including using cookies and skipping security protocol with the option -k, e.g.

```
curl --ntlm -u somename@somename.onmicrosoft.com:mypassword -k -O https://somename.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/filetodownload.pdf
```

or wget

```
wget -A pdf --no-check-certificate --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" --keep-session-cookies --cookies=on --user=somename@somename.onmicrosoft.com --password=mypassword https://somename.sharepoint.com
```

Researching previous answers it seems that curl seemed to have been working a few years back (on non-https sites). However, I cannot find a working solution for downloading from https sites. Is there a way to download files via command line either through curl/wget or any other method that I am currently not aware of?